# Its possible sort by multiple columns in awk?

Tags: awk

Sort By Third Column And Fourth  Column

Input

```
B,c,3,
G,h,2,
J,k,4,
M,n,,1
```

Output

```
M,n,,1
G,h,2,
B,c,3,
J,k,4,
```

Please help me

**UPDATED**

```
      awk -F, 'a[$3]<$4{a[$3]=$4;b[$3]=$0}END{for(l in a){print b[l]","l} }' FILE2
```

i  use this command and i obtains

this

M,n,,1,

,2

,3

,4

Comment: you can use `gawk` and [Controlling-Scanning](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Scanning.html) ..... but .... @Sundeep solution said `sort` is better choice than `awk` for this

Comment: This was cross-posted.  http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/345883/135943

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sort` is better choice than `awk` here

```
$ sort -t, -k3,3n -k4,4n ip.txt 
M,n,,1
G,h,2,
B,c,3,
J,k,4,
```

- `-t,` use `,` as delimiter
- `-k3,3n` sort by 3rd column, numerically
- `-k4,4n` then sort by 4th column, numerically

Comment: HI THANK YOU FOR YOUR RESPONSE BUT HOW I CAN DOING THIS IN AWK IM USING THIS COMMAND BUT NOT WORKS                                    awk -F, 'a[$3]<$4{a[$3]=$4;b[$3]=$0}END{for(l in b){print b[l]}}' FILE2

Comment: IM USING AWK BECAUSE IS CROSSPLATFORM USING NAWK

Comment: awk -F, 'a[$3]<$4{a[$3]=$4;b[$3]=$0}END{for(l in a){print l","a[l]","b[l]}}' FILE2

Comment: @VictorHernandez STOP SHOUTING.

Comment: very   sorry :(  ,

Answer (score 0):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -F, '{a[$3,$4,NR]=$0} 
       END {n=asorti(a,ix);
            for(k=1;k<=n;k++) print a[ix[k]]}' file

M,n,,1
G,h,2,
B,c,3,
J,k,4,
```

note that key is constructed in a such a way to handle duplicate rows

if you don't have `asorti` here's a workaround

```
$ awk -F, '{a[$0]=$3 FS $4 FS NR RS $0} 
       END {n=asort(a);
            for(k=1;k<=n;k++) 
              {sub(".*"RS,"",a[k]);
               print a[k]}}' file
```

I used RS as a secondary delimiter to keep the line separate from the sort key.  Note duplicate rows will be counted as one (duplicate keys are fine).  If you want to support duplicate rows change to `a[$0,NR]`

Comment: hi very thankyou but asort appear not defined ; i have a command but i dont know in that part i get a error please see my command

Comment: this is my command  
awk -F, 'a[$3]<$4{a[$3]=$4;b[$3]=$0}END{for(l in a){print l","a[l]","b[l]}}' FILE2

Comment: your command doesn't seem right, not clear what you're comparing. Please see the updated solution.

Comment: I UPDATED THE QUESTION

Answer (score 0):

I use this command and it works:

```
nawk -F, '{a[$3]<$4;a[$3]=$4;b[$3]=$0} END{for(i in a){print b[i]}}'   FILE2
```